# Finding documentation in XCode 4.5

Tags: xcode4.5

I'm very used to option clicking on something in XCode, and then clicking the "notebook" icon in the top right, to bring up the appropriate documentation (see the image below).

Where has this icon gone in XCode 4.5? (i.e. how do I get to the documentation in 4.5?)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click on the link in the reference section of the popup, it will take you to the documentation section of organizer.  I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for as I have never used the feature pre 4.5.  Just tested this on my computer and it worked though.